# Your CPU does not support KVM extensions - Virtualization is On

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, windows, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I am trying to use KVM using VirtualBox running an Ubuntu 20.04.06 focal ISO image. When I enter the command kvm-ok it shows me this  output:

```
INFO: Your CPU does not support KVM extensions
KVM acceleration can NOT be used.
```

I have tried:

- I went to my BIOS and Virtualization VTx is already enabled.
- I disabled the virtual machine feature and made sure Hyper-V is disabled to avoid conflicts according to my research.
- I downloaded the KVM packages in the Ubuntu terminal and I tried with the GUI interface.
- I made sure VTx is enabled in VirtualBox.
- I restarted my PC.
- And I spent countless hours watching videos and reading forums, but I haven't found a fix.

Information about my laptop:

```
OS Name: Microsoft Windows 11 Home   
Version: 10.0.22631 Build 22631  
OS Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation  
System Model: Katana 17 B13VFK  
System Type : x64-based PC  
Processor: 13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-13620H, 2400 Mhz, 10 Core(s), 16 Logical Processor(s)  
BIOS Version/Date: American Megatrends International, LLC. E17L5IMS.113, 10/26/2023  
SMBIOS Version: 3.5  
BaseBoard Manufacturer: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd.  
Platform Role: Mobile  
PCR7 Configuration: Elevation Required to View  
Hardware Abstraction Layer: Version = "10.0.22621.2506"  
Time Zone: Central America Standard Time  
Installed Physical Memory (RAM): 32.0 GB  
Page File Space: 4.75 GB  
Page File: C:\pagefile.sys  
Kernel DMA Protection: On  
Virtualization-based security: Running  
Virtualization-based security Required Security Properties    
Virtualization-based security Services: Configured  Hypervisor enforced Code Integrity  
Virtualization-based security Services: Running Hypervisor enforced Code Integrity  
Windows Defender Application Control policy: Enforced  
Windows Defender Application Control user mode policy:   Off  
Device Encryption Support: Elevation Required to View  
Virtualization-based security Available Security   Properties: Base Virtualization Support, Secure Boot, DMA Protection, UEFI Code Readonly, SMM Security Mitigations 1.0, Mode Based Execution Control, APIC Virtualization
```

A hypervisor has been detected. Features required for Hyper-V will not be displayed.

I believe this machine must run KVM somehow, but I don't know what else to try.

Comment: Your "Information about my laptop:" describes Windows. Please boot to Linux and post one block (all CPU cores are the same) of `/proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: root@UbuntuKVM:/home/lttrs# /proc/cpuinfo
bash: /proc/cpuinfo: Permission denied
root@UbuntuKVM:/home/lttrs# cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor : 0
vendor_id : GenuineIntel
cpu family : 6
model  : 186
model name : 13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-13620H
stepping : 2
microcode : 0xffffffff
cpu MHz  : 2918.396
cache size : 24576 KB
physical id : 0
siblings : 5
core id  : 0
cpu cores : 5
apicid  : 0
initial apicid : 0
fpu  : yes
fpu_exception : yes
cpuid level : 22
wp  : yes

Comment: flags: fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch ibrs_enhanced fsgsbase bmi1 bmi2 invpcid rdseed clflushopt arat md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities
bugs : spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass swapgs retbleed eibrs_pbrsb
bogomips: 5836.79
clflush size: 64
cache_alignment: 64
address sizes : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power manageme

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me Daniel ! I am sorry I had to split the core description into two. I am new here. If you need more info let me know. I will keep searching for a solution.

Comment: I don't think you properly "made sure VTx is enabled in VirtualBox". I should see "vmx" in there if it's actually enabled. By the way, please [edit] your posts when posting blocks of information next time

Comment: I apologize for the unedited comment. I will check that to understand how my comments can be properly uploaded next time.

Just to understand you said that VMX isn't showing. But to give more context, at first in VirtualBox the option came disabled, or grayed-out. However, I use my local CMD turning on that option and I can confirm is marked in VirtualBox. Is there other step I am missing further than that?

Comment: Cmd? Are you trying to do nested virtualization? There's a checkbox for that in virtualbox

Comment: Ok, this sounds like I may be taking some extra steps then.

My goal is to use Ubuntu 64-bit version using VirtualBox. 
After that, I need to use KVM to take advantage of its hypervisor capabilities tu run other ISOs.

However, according to the research I made, when I used the kvm-ok command it was giving me an error message due to VT-x not being checked.

Then I went to Virtualbox and I saw the option grayed-out. If you have a AMD processor that option is available. But my PC is Intel, then I had to go to Cmd, going to Oracle/Virtualbox and run a command to enable it which I did.

Comment: Although the option is now marked, the error message is still showing. Ubuntu is fully updated, and VTx is enabled as well. I don't know if VTx works along with the VMX you mentioned, or I may be missing something.

Comment: See the answer at https://askubuntu.com/a/1502897/1004020